# VHDL Trying to give a signal as an input

Tags: vhdl

This is my code:

```
    LIBRARY  ieee;
    USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
    USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
    
    ENTITY TEST_ALUCONTROL_ALU IS PORT (     
     OP_5to0 : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 DOWNTO 0);
     ALU_op  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
     ALUin1  : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     ALUin2  : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     ALUout1 : OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     zero    : OUT std_logic);
    END TEST_ALUCONTROL_ALU;
    
    
    
    
    ARCHITECTURE structural OF TEST_ALUCONTROL_ALU IS
    SIGNAL U1_OUT  : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
    SIGNAL U2_OUT  : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
    COMPONENT ALU_Control PORT(
        OP_5to0    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 DOWNTO 0);
        ALU_op     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
        Operation  : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
    END COMPONENT;
    
    COMPONENT ALU_4 PORT(
        ALUin1  : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        ALUin2  : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        ALUctrl : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        ALUout1 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        zero    : OUT STD_LOGIC);
    END COMPONENT;
    
    BEGIN
       a:ALU_Control PORT MAP(OP_5to0=>OP_5to0,ALU_op=>ALU_op,Operation=>U1_OUT);
       b:ALU_4       PORT MAP(ALUin1=>ALUin1,ALUin2=>ALUin2,ALUctrl=>U2_OUT,ALUout1=>ALUout1,zero=>zero);
U2_OUT<=U1_OUT;
         
         
    END structural;
```

Those are the components
ALU4:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


    entity ALU4 is port (
        ALUin1  : in std_logic_vector  (3 downto 0);
        ALUin2  : in std_logic_vector  (3 downto 0);
        ALUctrl : in std_logic_vector  (3 downto 0);
        ALUout1 : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        zero    : out std_logic);
    end ALU4;
    
    
    architecture behavioural of ALU4 is
    signal OUTPUT: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    
    
    begin
    process(ALUin1,ALUin2,ALUctrl)
    begin
        if ALUctrl="0000" then
            OUTPUT<=ALUin1 AND ALUin2;
        elsif ALUctrl="0001" then
            OUTPUT<=ALUin1 OR ALUin2;
        elsif ALUctrl="0010" then
            OUTPUT<=ALUin1 + ALUin2;
        elsif ALUctrl="0110" then
            OUTPUT<=ALUin1 - ALUin2;
        elsif ALUctrl="0111" then
            if ALUin1-ALUin2<0 then
                    OUTPUT<="0001";
            else    OUTPUT<="0000";
            end if;
        end if;
        end process;
        
    ALUout1 <= OUTPUT;
    
    zero<='1' when OUTPUT="0000" 
    ELSE '0';
    end behavioural;
```

and AlU_Control:

```
LIBRARY ieee ;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY ALU_Control IS PORT (
  OP_5to0   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 DOWNTO 0);
  ALU_op    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
  Operation : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
END ALU_Control;

ARCHITECTURE AlUControl of ALU_Control is
BEGIN
  Operation(3) <= '0'; 
  Operation(2) <= ALU_op(0) or (ALU_op(1) and OP_5to0(1)); 
  Operation(1) <= not ALU_op(1) or not OP_5to0(2); 
  Operation(0) <= (OP_5to0(3) or OP_5to0(0)) and ALU_op(1);
END AlUControl;
```

Im trying to give  Operation of Alu_control component as an input to ALUctrl of ALU_4 component but i cant figure out how. I don't know  why ALUout1 don't have any outputs even if im connecting it with U2_OUT signal. Any help would be apreciated.

[Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6xB3.png)

Comment: I don't immediately see a problem with the code you have posted. What results are you seeing vs. what results you expected?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As you can see in the picture i've added, i want to give U2_OUT as an input to the ALU_4 component for it to produce the ALUout1 output but the ALUout1 does not working at all.

Comment: Have you written the `ALU_4` component?

Comment: Yes i have writte them all,i will provide them.

Comment: Thanks. It is hard to debug this by just looking at the code. You could try setting this up in https://www.edaplayground.com/ and providing the link, that would let people simulate and debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a driver on the signal U2_OUT.

Furthermore, ALU_Control drives the signal U1_OUT, and so does ALU_4.  Which creates a conflict and you'll get X's on this bus.

Sort out your wiring, and don't confuse a signal name with a port name.